# Understanding backpropagation with softmax

Tags: python, neural-network, softmax

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, but I just can't wrap my head around this.
I am trying to create my first neural network, which takes MNIST data (28x28) on which are hand-drawn numbers 0-9 and output which digit neural networks thinks it is. In the last layer, I need to do a softmax function, which can output all the probabilities of those numbers, which then sum up to 1.

```
def softmax(z):
    exps = np.exp(z - z.max())

    return exps/np.sum(exps), z
```

To this point, everything should be fine.
But now we get to the backpropagation part => I have found out on the internet this softmax function for backpropagation.

```
def softmax_backward(dA, Z):
    x, _ =softmax(dA)
    s=x.reshape(-1,1)

    return (np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T))
```

**Question 1: Is this softmax derivative function suitable for my NN?**

If it is suitable, then I have error somewhere else.
This is my error:

> ````
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-21-b0721d5dd18f> in <module>
> ---> 26 parameters = model(x_testone, y_testone, layer_dims)
>
> <ipython-input-20-0653ba2ad7e6> in model(X, y, layer_dims,
> learning_rate, epochs, print_cots, activation)
>      10         zCache = zCaches[l+1]
>      11 
> ---> 12         grads = L_model_backward(Al, y, linCaches, zCaches, activation)
>      13 
>      14         parameters = update_parameters(parameters, grads, learning_rate)
>
> <ipython-input-18-8b76528a319a> in L_model_backward(Al, y, linCaches,
> zCaches, activation)
> ---> 11     grads["dA" + str(L-1)], grads["dW" + str(L)], grads["db" + str(L)] = liner_activ_backward(dAl, zCaches[L-1], linCaches[L-1],
> "softmax")
>      12 
>
> <ipython-input-17-6e9b3ba31571> in liner_activ_backward(dA, zCache,
> linCache, activation)
>      20         dZ = softmax_backward(dA, Z)
> ---> 21         dA_prev, dW, db = linear_backward(dZ, linCache)
>      22         return dA_prev, dW, db
>      23 
>
> <ipython-input-16-4b15b65d0522> in linear_backward(dZ, linCache)
> ----> 7     dW = (1/m) * np.dot(dZ, A_prev.T)
>       8     db = (1/m) * np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
>       9     dA_prev = np.dot(W.T, dZ)
>
> ValueError: shapes (10000,10000) and (20,1000) not aligned: 10000 (dim
> 1) != 20 (dim 0) ```
> ````

Now I think that my error is in `liner_backward` method, because it's not compatible with softmax. Am I right with this, or totally wrong?

**Question 2: What method should I use instead of `linear_backward` method?**

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Sorry for making this a comment and not an answer, but I don't fully understand your question.  The backprop derivative is literally the calculus derivative of an objective function.  You have to pick the objective function before you can determine what the backprop derivative is.  Have you selected one?

Comment: I am here the one who should be sorry. Clearly my understanding of the basics of neural networks are not complete. Also the fact that I am on High school and don't know calculus yet, makes it harder to understand anything.

By objective function you mean cost function, right? If yes, then I would like to use cross-entropy function

Comment: @Lukas Step 1: Go back and learn calculus, you need it. Step 2: Get comfortable taking derivatives and working with vectors and matrices (don't worry about tensors yet). Step 3: Learn backpropagation and understand it, try to derive it yourself to be sure you understand it. Step 4: Write the code

Answer (score 0):

Softmax accepts a vector as an input and gives a vector as an output, hence it is meaningless to define a "gradient" for softmax. The derivative of softmax is given by its Jacobian Matrix, which is just a neat way of writing all the combinations of derivatives of outputs with respect to all inputs.

One use case of softmax is in the output layer of classification-based sequential networks, where it is used along with the Categorical Cross Entropy loss function. The usual workaround to prevent computing the Jacobian of the softmax, is to simply take derivatives of the Loss function, with respect to the inputs passed to softmax, instead of the outputs passed by softmax.

Therefore, you could simply write the softmax backward function, to pass the output gradients obtained from the "next layer" (loss function), to the "previous layer".

```
def softmax_backward(dA):
    return dA
```

Note that it is the duty of the layer that comes before the softmax, to implement a backward function to compute the required derivatives of the loss function with respect to that layer's parameters, when given the gradients from the Loss function.

Insightful resources:

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDNU6R1_67000Dx_ZCJB-3pi

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pauPCy_s0Ok

https://towardsdatascience.com/derivative-of-the-softmax-function-and-the-categorical-cross-entropy-loss-ffceefc081d1

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2016/the-softmax-function-and-its-derivative/

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQVvvaa0QuDcjD5BAw2DxE6OF2tius3V3